# How to improve my code so that it wouldn't terminate due to timeout?(HackerRank challenge)

Tags: c++, timeout

My code works pretty well, but when I submit it on HackerRank, it shows me the error of "Your code did not execute within the time limits" for a few cases, and "success" for the rest of the cases.
Here's the link to the HackerRank challenge and what the code is required to do:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/problem
Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k, q, count=0, index;
    cin>>n>>k>>q;
    int ar[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin>>ar[i];
    }
    int m[q];
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        cin>>m[i];
    }
    while (count != k)
    {
        for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            swap(ar[i],ar[i-1]);
        }
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        index=m[i];
        cout<<ar[index]<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: it is not necessary to actually physically move any elements just to determine which element will land at a given index after the rotations. It's simple arithmetic.

Comment: @OP These questions on sites like HackerRank are designed so that naive solutions can be coded, but will almost always fail due to timeout issues.  There is no need to loop for a problem like this.  If you had a 12-hour clock, and you were asked "what time would it be if I add 143 hours?", would you actually need to turn the minute hand 143 times around the clock to figure out the time?  That's what your code is doing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Nice example, thanks :D

Comment: Rotation problems, clock arithmetic problems, etc. are really questions on modulo/remainder arithmetic.  You just need to come up with the correct formula.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This is now scratching my brain... I'm gonna go for it, thanks! :D

Comment: Your link doesn't work unless you sign up for that site. That's why you should put the explanation of what the code is supposed to do in the question, not in a link.

Comment: @PeteBecker Your'e doing sth wrongly, it never forces you to sign up. It only suggests you and you can reject signing up, and you'll be able to see the challenge. I also never signed up for that site. Neither did my friends whom I sent this link to. I'm positive that others here have successfully viewed the challenge without signing up/in.

Comment: @Liana -- I might have overreacted to that popup.

Answer (score 0):

How about considering setting the starting point of the array to a variable, and calculate this variable to avoid loops.Maybe many loops or int ar[n](I don't know the oj if it supports).
and the solution may like:

```cpp
for(...){
    ++pos;
    if (pos == k) pos = 0;
}
```

so what you should do is output the array from pos to end,and 0 to pos

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in O(N*N) but it can be done in O(N). So I request you to go through this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/.  In case any doubts comment them down.

Comment: From reading the question, it doesn't need any loops whatsoever.  It can be done in O(1).

Comment: Actually some of the competitive coding questions are poorly stated. They just ask to print the modified array but that can directly done without modifying it and directly printing them. For example in this problem we can directly print the values without even modifying the array. But I feel it's not the correct way and one should always do it perfectly.